# will google crawl be able to check links that gets added dynamically as the user scrolls down

Tags: seo, google

I am designing a website, which will display 5 records initially and as the user scrolls down, it will keep loading contents like facebook news feed.

If i submit this site to google for crawling, will it scroll down and navigate to all links or will it just visit the first 5 links that gets loaded initially?

P.S I will also be creating a sitemap and submit it as suggested [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769?vid=1-635750346106212011-4281645217902877188)

Answer (score 1):

Google now are able to crawl dynamically generated content with javascript, but i don't know if they also crawl javascript that requiring scrolling down page for more content to be generated. Take a look at this http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157

Comment: You have a timeframe of app. 3-4s. Content that is not rendered then will not be crawled/indexed. You can che it by using "fetch as googlebot and render" feature in Google Search Console.

Answer (score 1):

If you append a parameter to the URL like # or !, then it's possible to have them indexed. http://example.com/#about